# Vue js Production Deployment

Tags: vue.js

I am using the command 'npm run build' for production deployment of my vue project.In the build folder i have build.js and webpack.dev.conf.js, webpack.prod.conf.js etc.When i run the command it will run succesfully and it creates a dist folder with index.html , static folder(css.img.js) and _redirects file.But why it not taking into account my other files.all the components are inside the src folder.The folder structure is as shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfFF1.png)

Why it not taking the src folder?

Following is the screenshot of the deployed application.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KddW7.png)

Following is the error log from console.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YepOQ.png)

Comment: It did, the `build` folder is the "compiled" version of your whole app.  What makes you think that it didn't actually build?

Comment: when i deployed it in tomcat,it was not showing the required pages

Comment: Can you deploy on nginX ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV  i will try that.so i have a basic doubt .My src folder is also compiled ?How can i make sure that? I have 7 folders inside the src folder in which i have placed my .vue files inside the components folder

Comment: Everything that comprises your single-page JavaScript application has been minified and bundled inside the `dist` folder. You are supposed to deploy in the root folder of your domain name - unless you have configured a non-default `publicPath` in your `vue.config.js`

Comment: Yes i got my application running.But still confused with one issue.In the tomcat webapps folder i have ROOT folder as wel as the non-default publicPath i have defined in config file.(Myproject).When i start the tomcat server and i go to localhost:8080/Myproject am only able to properly run if the contents of dist files is copied to both the Root folder as well as Myproject folder @IVO GELOV

Comment: What happens if you deploy the files only inside `Myproject` ? The purpose of the `publicPath` config variable is exactly for this - so that the bundle is compiled for the proper folder on production.

Comment: if i deploy the files only on Myproject its not running as expected.it is showing the same screen as i have posted in my question @IVOGELOV.i can run it successfully if i copy files on both root and Myproject folders

Comment: is it connected with my routes.js ?